# WPF ItemsControl datacontext sorting

Tags: wpf, data-binding, sorting, itemscontrol

Ok, I have an `ItemsControl` binded to a `List<IComparableObject>`, each second the `List` objects change, so I have to resort them, so each second I call the `List.Sort()` method. Checking in the Watch panel in VS2008, I can tell the `List` gets sorted, but the `ItemsControl` doesn't. How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to sort the CollectionView:

```
 List<MyObject> myInternalList = new List<MyObject>();
 ...
 ICollectionView colView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myInternalList);
 colView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

You have to get the default view from the List. 
In this case, you don't have to sort the List, because the view will always be sorted. You can add as many SortDescriptions you want.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I have another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250953/sorting-in-window-datacontext-in-wpf Maybe you can help out with this one too. Thanks!!

Comment: @Roel Can we apply culture specific sort with this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332882/culture-specific-sorting-on-icollectionview