# Sorting in window datacontext in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, datacontext

Another question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243274/wpf-itemscontrol-datacontext-sorting).

I have a `List<SortableObjects>` that is the `DataContext` of my MainWindow. I use that list to populate a `ListBox` and a `ComboBox`. When I sort the items, both the `ComboBox` and the `ListView` get updated all right. But now I need the `ComboBox` to be sorted in a different way than the `ListView`. I. E. If the object were a Person, in the `ComboBox`, I'd need to sort them by LastName, but in the `ListView`, by birthday. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)s for each of the separate orderings you want:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ComboBoxSource" Source="{Binding YourUnderlyingCollection}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SomeProperty"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ListBoxSource" Source="{Binding YourUnderlyingCollection}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SomeOtherProperty"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboBoxSource}}"/>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListBoxSource}}"/>
```